# В Ке́рчи или в Керчи́?

Tags: грамотная-речь, орфоэпия, склонение, ономастика

Где правильно ставить ударение при склонении: в Ке́рчи или  в Керчи́?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Тут ударение однозначно ставится на Е.
"В К**е**рчи", "из К**е**рчи".

Answer (score 3):

[Словарь имён собственных](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&ro=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D0%9A%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%87%D1%8C):
Керчь, Ке́рчи, к Ке́рчи, **в Ке́рчи** (гор., Крым, РФ).

Такого же мнения придерживается и ["Грамота"](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=%D0%9A%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%87%D1%8C#:%7E:text=%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0%20%D0%9A%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%87%D1%8C%3F&text=%D0%A3%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%20%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%20%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B5%3A%20%D0%B8%D0%B7,%D1%80%D1%87%D0%B8%2C%20%D0%B2%20%D0%9A%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%87%D0%B8.).

**Вопрос № 289562**
На какой слог падает ударение в р. п. города Керчь?
**Ответ справочной службы русского языка**
Ударение остается на корне: из К**е**рчи, к К**е**рчи, в К**е**рчи.

[Словарь собственных имён русского языка](https://books.google.ee/books?id=i5e8DwAAQBAJ&pg=PA26&lpg=PA26&dq=%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8%20%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F%D1%85,%20%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B8%D1%85%D1%81%D1%8F%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%20%D0%BC%D1%8F%D0%B3%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9%20%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9&source=bl&ots=fs07UWhVpL&sig=ACfU3U1ooNxmGpfsdt7phpUDhG7lojQLYA&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjlqaDrioPvAhVSmIsKHQsLDAQQ6AEwBHoECAoQAw#v=onepage&q=%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8%20%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F%D1%85%2C%20%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B8%D1%85%D1%81%D1%8F%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%20%D0%BC%D1%8F%D0%B3%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9%20%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9&f=false) (Ф. Агеенко):
Керчь, Ке́рчи, к Ке́рчи, **в Ке́рчи** (в последнем случае ударение закрепилось на основе).

*А там, под вывеской, где сельди из Ке́рчи —

сбитый старикашка шарил очки

и заплакал, когда в вечереющем смерче

трамвай с разбега взметнул зрачки.*
В. В. Маяковский

Мнения и примеры: ["Большой вопрос.ru"](http://www.bolshoyvopros.ru/questions/2189745-kak-pravilno-v-kerchi-ili-v-kerchi.html).

Comment: Конечно,знатоки русского языка лучше знают, как правильно склонять название города Керчь, чем местные жители. И правила какие-то подводят под это, а как же Тверь или, скажем, Пермь?

Answer (score 1):

Подходящего словаря под рукой нет, но местные жители говорят только "в КерчИ". При этом чаще встречается "о Керчи". Думаю, этот вариант вполне возможен по аналогии с "В шерстИ, (широк) в кости" и "о шерсти, о кОсти".
Т. е. тут имеет место "местный предложный" падеж.

Answer (score -2):

Характерно, что сегодняшние "лингвисты", составители словарей, не приводят аргументов в пользу написания. Почему? - потому что их нет. Кроме "частного мнения". Простейшее сравнение (в печИ, в ночИ, в ТверИ, в дверИ, в КерчИ) для них НИЧЕГО не значит. Люди, говорящие на финно-угорском диалекте русского языка, составляют словари ЛИТЕРАТУРНОГО языка. В литературном языке "ударение при склонении смещается"(правило). Но для "светил" есть удобная лазейка под названием "исключение", которым они пользуются, когда захотят. Отсюда казАк-казАки (рыбак-рыбАки?), обеспЕчение (обознАчение? огранИчение?) и масса "перлов московской словесности".