# Слова "вроде (бы)", "однозначно" вводные?

Tags: пунктуация, вводные-слова

У нас с behemothus-ом в комментариях к [его ответу](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/420285/%D0%9D%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BB/420287#comment420997_420287) зашёл спор, считать ли ***вроде бы*** или ***вроде*** вводным словом или нет. Он считает, что это вводное слово, а мне не хочется выделять его запятыми, но объяснить почему сложно и нет полной уверенности, что оно не вводное. Behemothus обещал задать вопрос об этом, но, наверно, забыл или ещё не успел, поэтому я решил не тянуть, тем более добавилось ещё, что приплюсовать к нему.

Буквально только что увидел, как в [этом](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/703/%D0%A3%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B2-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8) вопросе о том, как правильно: "в К**е**рчи" или "в Керч**и**", Fuchoin Kazuki отвечает: "Тут ударение, *однозначно,* ставится на Е", очевидно, считая ***однозначно*** вводным словом.

*Итак, могут ли эти слова быть вводными в этих случаях и вообще или нет?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> “вроде (бы)”, “однозначно”… могут ли эти слова быть вводными?

Эти слова сравнительно редко употребляются в функции вводных, тем не менее ничего предосудительного в таком их использовании, по-моему, нет.

См. *Остроумова О., Фрамполь О.  "Трудности русской пунктуации. Словарь вводных слов, сочетаний и предложений"*:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо, Слава! А как в этом случае с *однозначно*, по-Вашему (в моей цитате Fuchion Kazuki)?

Comment: _Артём Луговой: А как в этом случае..._ === По-моему, в таких случаях надо соглашаться с автором. Как он считает, так пусть и будет.

Comment: В том смысле, что править не надо, наверно, Вы правы. Я и не стал. Конечно, должно быть как автор хочет, если это допустимо. Просто мне интересны конкретные мнения. Вот лично Вы бы поставили или нет?

Comment: _Артём Луговой: Вот лично Вы бы..._ === Лично я бы, говоря об ударении в словоформе "(в) Керчи", вообще  бы отказался от слова "однозначно".  Принятый ответ -- "Тут ударение, **однозначно**, ставится на Е" -- при любой пунктуации останется, по-моему, неправильным. Откуда может взяться _однозначность_, если в "Словаре ударений" на Грамоте -- "в К**е**рчи", у Зализняка -- второй предложный падеж с ударением на окончании? Правильный ответ, по моему мнению, в той теме у  behemothus'а.

Comment: Понятно, спасибо за ответ! Кстати "===" что-то означает или просто для красоты? =)