# "Вроде бы" — вводное слово или нет?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, вводные-слова

*Вместе с женой, тоже школьным учителем, Шидан в конце месяца приносил домой примерно $3600. Сумма, вроде бы, солидная.* В данном предложении и контексте нужно обособлять "вроде бы"? Был подробный ответ ранее - [Слова "вроде (бы)", "однозначно" вводные?](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/420381/%D0%A1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0-%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5-%D0%B1%D1%8B-%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%B2%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5) Но я не могу понять, у меня здесь "вроде бы" как вводное слово или нет?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Сумма вроде бы солидная.**

Практически  ***вроде бы*** считается частицей и не обособляется, что видно по большинству примеров в Нацкорпусе. Обособление, вероятно, следует отнести к авторской пунктуации.

Вот обычный пример: **Компания вроде бы солидная и уважаемая**, но...

Answer (score 1):

Не вижу причин обособлять *вроде бы*. А вот то, что жена помогала Шидану нести деньги домой (тяжелая была ноша, наверное), меня удивило. И почему Ваша супруга взялась помогать этому Шидану? А серьезно говоря, неподходящий случай, по-моему, для ед.ч. сказуемого. А слово *жена* означает супругу рассказчика. Как компромисс, чтобы сохранить разговорный стиль, я бы написал: *со своей (Шидана) женой*. Фраза требует перестройки.

**Шидан с супругой (со своей женой), тоже школьным учителем, вместе приносили домой в конце месяца примерно $3600. Сумма вроде бы солидная.**

**Шидан и его супруга (жена), тоже школьный учитель, вместе приносили домой в конце месяца примерно $3600. Сумма вроде бы солидная.**